# What happens when mandatory RVO is applied to a reference that's extending the lifetime of a temporary?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, return-value-optimization

When a reference is initialized with another reference that's extending the lifetime of a temporary, this new reference doesn't extend anything.

But what happens when mandatory RVO prevents the reference from being copied?

Consider this example: [run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRABOUlfQAZPLUwAcs4ARpjEXABspAAOqEKE5rR2ji7uMXEJdL7%2BQU6h4ZxRxpimiQwEzMQEyc6uHsWldOWVBNmBIWGRRhVVNan1Pa1%2B7XmdhQCURqgOxMgcUjoAzH7IjlgA1JqLNuZCBMSYzE5b2JoyAIJn53vEDqbrlxeaAOz6F%2BsfDxDjm6976CAUNMCJttlsbJttNpzt9NABWGy0HTaLb6Z4AESuny%2BaFoewekIiPy26PWWHYBEwqKxn3OhNQ0TCzCIxBJEFx%2BLpOiJoNJ5MwlOp70%2BAD8YcS/gQAUCHCDweDIdoxbCEUiodSMVcXpjFm9Htd9ncQXqXnrsRyQVztBFmELLprdVqLjcjesbFrXjSPrp1sE7dr/Rc/CCnMw/LCnp7hR94fo4bpQwBPUIAfQctAcInQ8MxcNJEK0r3WaJ99rRpO1vx1Zs%2B/0BaFloPd20VAFp2/DEcj/RipJNWNI4fJXLJ5KhpO69AZ1kJprNMJDFpx5ARpHJxpMANYgbgADgAdIsZJw4doZBEIpxnjxFru4SppNxh2ux9J5EIQDJSKvR5M4LAYEQIEnGiPB2DICh2VQECwM6YBOAQvgwMpYgPwgYIX1IYI/EqRNpGXUg0CcJwrAIAB5WhWDw0dSCwUN1HYTD8AOUoADdMA/GjMHEEpZXmORyHoTABxo1g8GCYhcLsLB8JXYg8CcWTJn4RgWEYng%2BDoAhhDESQaKUTgVDUDQDAMFRxI/SBJgZMw6E41t/hJLQpz0M91lbAB1NhWHcjzuP2Zh3MZdA1DMZBWzCYgSCEd9hJKWzXAgLw%2BlcQyvDaXJ8mUWJ4gSlLsoyBKMo6AojDixpaGaXp7FqZQGgSqqhhyEq6sGfLDL2FpitGApJlnGY5i4ftB2fGjxykcRdwiVsIm4dZgGQZB1gQ/dOHWCBcEIEhF0Mt1oNA8Cdp%2BSd9D0FcXw3Uht0WOFDyXE84TcZ4oWeXcT14ESn1IRS4UWfdHuPNxrW4EHd0WRYohHATxvfT9vwu0h/yA4FollchKCIg6xk8fAWWUFSmDYDgNJUnSJEwgB3SToiUh8pCHUgodfKQyNlVGQVQKh1km6bZvmxbls4Vb1rsGDDqWThxnO39JgQQ4sHCb46a%2BxTuAifduBkNxdxkZ4brhOFClmxnMJhow4Z/dctxAbRbpkRY9bhXdXueNxuAdjwRMWUbobfeHf0RwCkYgJBMdgiCMf28OUFUdRODPL8qGQsI0IwmjsNoXDZMI6CSPoCiqKYzB6OARiaOY%2BK8HYziBO43jKUw4NhMwsSJKkjB5gI/YFNpgm1OJ3hSZEcn9Jtoz1BQUy9HM4JLKVmzEnsxzFnRZzTt0NzPO83z/MkoLMBC%2Bg8HCyLotikwEssax2s8axuqywycsyJIatSR/CsSe/sfqso2tf1KyoX1/l1YYmVv5/xSAAzqVQv69SmANYmw16Y%2B2ZjzGac1VjGWWtofcMhcHrU2iyHapA9pizCIubQx0p66GllbUgctmAK0oNbcG%2B4zzPFBq9OEzxnqvWVvIH6f1tCLDcEDUR3AOERBkI9e8TNSBmw/F%2BS2fZA7wBDiAFGaNIJh3AmPA%2BW1Sp9yJlwQeWkyZ6QElTZgNMpDLiQQzOR41WYEHZusTm3MproPWJg9Q2DcH4IgKLLGxAKFS39nQhhTClafQETudWzwpG6xkNI22IjNayNNn7RR4S%2BzW2tPuC8CEzwG3ttwTgu5tB029ibMaftlGXREtoFB8i6kXUmOxVCiQdxAA%3D)

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() {std::cout << "A()\n";}
    A(const A &) = delete;
    A &operator=(const A &) = delete;
    ~A() {std::cout << "~A()\n";}
};

struct B
{
    const A &a;
};

struct C
{
    B b;
};

int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] C c{ B{ A{} } };
    std::cout << "---\n";
}
```

Under GCC this prints

```
A()
---
~A()
```

but under Clang the result is

```
A()
~A()
---
```

Which compiler is correct?

On the first glance, GCC did the right thing. But in this example:

```
C foo()
{
    return { B{ A{} } };
}

int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] C c = foo();
    std::cout << "---\n";
}
```

the lifetime of `A` surely can't be extended beyond the function (and both compilers agree on this).

Since this snippet supposedly has the same RVO as the first one, shouldn't the behavior be the same? Thus Clang's behavior seems more consistent.

Comment: fyi - Interesting thing to try is add `-O3` and note that both compilers do not create the objects and only print the output.  At least the order of both is unchanged.

Comment: fyi2 - have added destructor instrumentation for `B` and `C` and I am now even more confused https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YqdYn95xP

Comment: @RichardCritten `B` is directly constructed in `c` because of RVO, so it makes sense.

Comment: I don't see where lifetime extension of a temporary should happen here. I would expect that Clang's output is correct, and the `B` in `C` would hold a dangling reference.

Comment: @j6t Why not? We initialize a reference with a temporary. It does happen [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9r6nbon7a), when RVO is not involved.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OK, looks like there are now [more situations](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6) when lifetime is extended than there used to be; a blanket "when a reference is bound to a temporary object" being the cruical condition now.

Comment: In the second case, compilers are allowed to create a temporary object https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.temporary#3

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Interesting. I wonder why that section is even there, since the as-if rule should allow the same optimizations. But it can be easily defeated by removing trivial-ness, which [doesn't affect the behavior](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/abY84a5cz), so that's not what prevents the lifetime extension.

Comment: _I wonder why that section is even there, since the as-if rule should allow the same optimizations_ The difference between introducing and not introducing a temporary object can be observable. _so that's not what prevents the lifetime extension_ It is https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.temporary#6.2

Comment: The example can be further simplified, eliminating class ```C```: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KP3c6cv8Y

Comment: @LanguageLawyer *"It is"* What is mean is, since adding non-trivial-ness didn't change anything, `[class.temporary]/3` is not the culprit. I'm unsure about `[class.temporary]/6.2`, to me it reads like it only applies when the return type is a reference.

Comment: I mean forget about [class.temporary]/3, temporary object lifetimes are not extended when returning from function because of [class.temporary]/(6.2).

Comment: Just a thought about the wording: "_RVO prevents the reference from being copied_" - No references can be copied, so whatever RVO says about copy elision doesn't apply here if I'm correct.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm unsure. RVO applies to the enclosing class.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm onboard but I don't think a reference counts as an object.

Comment: it's about lifetime rules i think. Why rvo? may be gcc and clang authors have different understanding  about a scope where action taking place. It may be not optimized out.

Answer (score 10):

GCC is right.

In the second example we don’t have lifetime extension because of [[class.temporary] ¶6.11](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.11):

> The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function `return` statement ([[stmt.return]](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return)) is not extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the `return` statement.

If we re-wrote the example thus:

```
C foo(const A &a)
{
    return { B{ a } };
}

int main()
{
    C c = foo(A {});
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
}
```

[clause 6.9](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.9) would instead kick in:

> A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call ([[expr.call]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.call)) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.

Why then does lifetime extension apply in the first example?  Well, it’s simple: aggregate initialisers are not function calls.  They are described in different portions of the standard: function calls are described in [[expr.call]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.call), while initialisation expressions are described in [[expr.type.conv]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv) (and aggregate initialisation in [[dcl.init.aggr]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr)).

Note, however, that if `B` had an actual constructor:

```
struct B
{
    const A &a;
    B(const A &a_): a(a_) {}
};
```

then invoking that constructor counts as a function invocation, at which point [[class.temporary] ¶6.9](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.9) becomes relevant again.<sup>0</sup>  Without it, the reference members of aggregates are treated as if they were declared directly as variables, as far as lifetimes are concerned.

If you want to perform aggregate initialisation without temporary lifetime extension like Clang (incorrectly) does, you can use parentheses instead of braces for initialisation, which will trigger [[class.temporary] ¶6.10](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.10):

> A temporary object bound to a reference element of an aggregate of class type initialized from a parenthesized *expression-list* ([[dcl.init]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init)) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the *expression-list*.

Unfortunately, Clang apparently does not implement this currently, as this is a new addition to C++20 (proposal [P0960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html)).  Note that the text of that proposal even explicitly spells out that GCC’s behaviour wrt the first example is what’s intended by the standard.

---

<sup>0</sup> Presumably.  The clause only mentions function calls as described in [[expr.call]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.call), and I am having a hard time finding any clear statement in the standard that constructor calls are supposed to work the same way.

Comment: Hmm. To me `[class.temporary]/6.11` reads like it applies only when the return type is a reference, but I'm not sure. Because of *"value in a function return statement"* it shouldn't apply [when NRVO is used](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Wj3zov5zn), and yet there's no lifetime extension even in that case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Okay, this seems like a gap in the phrasing of the standard. But there isn’t any way to make lifetime extension work anyway, as the caller of the function has no way of taking ownership of another object, other than the return value. (Amusingly though, it looks like GCC is attempting to extend the lifetime regardless: the destructor of `A` is not called at all, as if the compiler expected the *caller* of `foo` to destroy the object – which it of course cannot.)

Comment: Yep, I've just [reported it to GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101442). I know it's impossible, I'm just hoping there's some wording that more clearly forbids it.